# hide items from left to right on overflow

Tags: html, css

I have a div with children and I want to hide items if there is not enough space for them, but hide from flex-start instead of flex-end

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2 </div>
  <div class="child">3 </div>
</div>
```

Here I want to see containers 2 and 3 instead of 1 and 2

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you want. Are all children to be on the one line however much overflow there is? (I am confused because of the 'wrap' in the CSS).

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your question properly.

```css
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child{
  height: 30px;
  min-width: 50px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
  <div class="child">6</div>
  <div class="child">7</div>
  <div class="child">8</div>
  <div class="child">9</div>
  <div class="child">10</div>
  <div class="child">11</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Erkan, thank you for the answer, it is close, but not what I'm looking for: in this case if there is enough space for all items, they will be positioned to the right border, but I want them to start from the left